# What does the {$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB} compiler directive mean?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, tms, compiler-directives, tms-web-core

I'm looking through the `WEBLib.StdCtrls` source code in TMS Web Core and regularly I see a `{$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}` compiler directive such as here with the `TWebLabel` component:

```
{$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
[ComponentPlatforms(TMSWebPlatform)]
{$ENDIF}
TWebLabel = class(TWebCustomLabel)
private
  FOnTouchMove: TTouchEvent;
  FOnTouchStart: TTouchEvent;
  FOnTouchEnd: TTouchEvent;
  FOnTouchCancel: TTouchEvent;
published
  property Align;
  property Alignment;
  {$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
  property AlignWithMargins;
  {$ENDIF}
  property Anchors;
  property AutoSize;
  property Caption;
  property ChildOrder;
  property Color;
  property DragMode;
  property ElementClassName;
  property ElementLabelClassName;
  property ElementID;
  property ElementFont;
  property ElementPosition;
  {$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
  property EllipsisPosition;
  {$ENDIF}
  property Enabled;
  property FocusControl;
  property Font;
  property Height;
  property HeightStyle;
  property HeightPercent;
  property Hint;
  property HTML;
  property HTMLType;
  property Layout;
  property Left;
  {$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
  property Margins;
  {$ENDIF}
  property ParentFont;
  property PopupMenu;
  property Role;
  property ShowAccelChar;
  property ShowHint;
  property TextDirection;
  property Top;
  property Transparent default true;
  property Visible;
  property Width;
  property WordWrap;
  property WidthStyle;
  property WidthPercent;
  property OnClick;
  property OnDblClick;
  property OnMouseDown;
  property OnMouseMove;
  property OnMouseUp;
  property OnMouseLeave;
  property OnMouseEnter;
  property OnTouchStart: TTouchEvent read FOnTouchStart write FOnTouchStart;
  property OnTouchEnd: TTouchEvent read FOnTouchEnd write FOnTouchEnd;
  property OnTouchMove: TTouchEvent read FOnTouchMove write FOnTouchMove;
  property OnTouchCancel: TTouchEvent read FOnTouchCancel write FOnTouchCancel;
  property OnDragDrop;
  property OnDragOver;
  property OnEndDrag;
  property OnStartDrag;
end;
```

You'll see the following in various places:

```
{$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
  // Some code for the compiler directive
{$ENDIF}
```

What is `LCLTMSWEB` and what does the `{$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}` compiler directive check for?

---

LCL = Lazarus?

So does the following line mean that the `AlignWithMargins` and `Margins` properties aren't available in Lazarus for TMS Web Core, but is available in all other platforms?:

```
{$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
property AlignWithMargins;
{$ENDIF}
```

and

```
{$IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB}
property Margins;
{$ENDIF}
```

So if you're using Lazarus with TMS Web Core, can you not set margin properties?

---

Maybe another side question if the above is true:

Why would some properties be available in Delphi, but not in Lazarus? Since TMS Web Core simply compiles the Object Pascal to JavaScript. Why can't the properties be available in both?

Comment: Since you seem to have the source code for TMS Web Core, can't you just look at where it is defining `LCLTMSWEB` and see the condition that TMS is defining it under? In any case, Lazarus/LCL is not up-to-speed on all the new features that exist in Delphi VCL/FMX in recent years, so it makes sense that TMS would want to filter out Delphi properties that don't exist in Lazarus.

Comment: Run [`findstr /s /i /c:"DEFINE LCLTMSWEB" *.pas`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findstr) from some base path, maybe also for `*.inc`.

Comment: This is to maintain compatibility with Lazarus Form Designer since at design-time, everything is rendered using LCL controls and therefore base property set is determined by LCL. I found this on [TMS Support Center](https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/lazarus-component-properties-missed-vs-visualstudio-vs-delphi/18881) after just a quick web search.

Comment: Aren't these questions you should be asking TMS support? They would be the ones with the most understanding of their source code and the reasoning behind decisions they've made.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thanks. I think that's exactly what I was looking for. That makes sense.